# Creating a duplicate row in a TableLayoutPanel with both ComboBoxes and TextBoxes?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox, tablelayoutpanel

Currently I have a program that filters search criteria by date. There are four different fields one can select (edited for confidentiality): Due Date, Start Date, Job 1 Due & Job 2 Due. The search criteria can be selected from a ComboBox with options All, Last Year, Last Month, Last Week, Today, This Week, This Month, This Year, Custom. Whatever range you select is then displayed in two text boxes next to the combo box, for the starting date of the filter and the ending date. The four ComboBoxes and eight associated TextBoxes are all in a control called a TableLayoutPanel.

I want to expand my program's flexibility by adding additional rows for filtering results. For example, maybe someone wants due dates This Week OR in a custom range in a couple months. The program currently works fine, it's just the only way I could get this to work is to create an entirely new row of ComboBoxes. I obviously need a mix of ComboBoxes and TextBoxes. I tried to create a List(Of List(Of Object)) but my code would throw errors. Here is some of the code:

```
Dim Boxes As List(Of List(Of ComboBox))
Private Sub AddRow1()
Try
    Dim z As Integer = 0
    TableLayoutPanel.RowCount += 1
    TableLayoutPanel.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows
    TableLayoutPanel.AutoSize = True
    TableLayoutPanel.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))
    For j = 0 To 11
        Boxes.Add(New List(Of ComboBox))
        Boxes.Item(TableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 3).Add(New ComboBox)
        If Boxes.Item(TableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 3).Item(j).Created = False Then
            Boxes.Item(TableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 3).Item(j).Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            AddHandler Boxes.Item(TableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 3).Item(j).TextChanged,   AddressOf Me.concat
            If (j = 0 Or j = 3 Or j = 6 Or j = 9) Then
                For Each it In Copy(z)
                    Boxes.Item(TableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 3).Item(j).Items.Add(it)
                Next
                z = z + 1
            End If
            If (j = 0 Or j = 3 Or j = 6 Or j = 9) Then
                Boxes.Item(TableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 3).Item(j).AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
                Boxes.Item(TableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 3).Item(j).AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
            End If
        End If

        TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(Boxes.Item(TableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 3).Item(j), j, TableLayoutPanel.RowCount - 1)

        Next
        DataGridView.Height = DataGridView.Height - 25
        DataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Creating a List(Of List(Of Object) would throw errors in the AddHandler method call and a few other places in this method,, but I believe that's what I need to be able to add a row of both ComboBoxes and TextBoxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `List(Of List(Of Control))`, and then potentially use TypeOf to make choices based on what control it actually is.

For example:

```
If TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox Then
   AddHandler CType(ctl, ComboBox).SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Handler1
ElseIf TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
   AddHandler CType(ctl, TextBox).TextChanged, AddressOf Handler2
End If
```

Also, note that a lot of events for different controls are named and decorated identically. `TextChanged` for a TextBox and ComboBox are exactly the same, and that one handler can handle the event for both types of controls.

Using Control instead of Object also specifies that type a lot more accurately, giving you access to many properties shared by all controls, such as Height, Text, etc.  The more accurately you can specify types, the easier it will be.

Comment: A List(Of Control) doesn't have an "Items" property: it's throwing an error in this line: Boxes.Item(TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 3).Item(j).Items.Add(it).  And it also throws errors in the section where I set comboBox properties, here: Boxes.Item(TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 3).Item(j).AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
                        Boxes.Item(TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 3).Item(j).AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend

Comment: That's because .Items() is defined on a ComboBox, not a Textbox or Control.  You'll need to cast it to ComboBox in order to use the properties of a combobox:   CType(Boxes(TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1).item(j), ComboBox).Items.Add(it)

Comment: For some reason, making that change now throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException()

Comment: Because I typo'd as I was copying.  Don't blindly copy and paste.  Examine it and see what it's doing, then apply it to your code. Otherwise, you'll never understand it

Comment: So, we now see how more generic types (such as Control), need to be cast to their more specific types (such as TextBox) because one can use the things defined on TextBox?  And, similarly, a more specific type already has access of all of the things defined on the more generic type by virtue of being a subclass of that type.  This will come up a LOT so be sure to play around with it and keep it in mind